# Will having short news articles on my site hurt the SEO of my more in depth articles?

Tags: seo, content, articles, word-count

My research says long thorough articles on a topic like 2k+ words really rank well in Google search results.

Google's algorithm doesn't treat short articles like 200+ words really well. Also, they aren't that good for the site SEO.

My question is what if I am publishing news articles 200 something words along with thorough long articles on a topic 2k+ words on my blog. Would short news articles affect the ranking of my website?

Comment: See also: [Is 100-150 words content enough for a web page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63499/is-100-150-words-content-enough-for-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 words is not a lot of content.  In general, I'd say 200 words is on the thin side and wouldn't usually answer searchers questions.   Most of the time searchers would be be happier with your longer articles.

200 words could be fine for some news though.  It might tell people what they need to know about a current event.  Having those short news blurbs could be good for users in the right context.

Are those short news blurbs going to hurt the SEO of your longer more in depth content?  Probably not.   It is likely that Google will send more traffic to your longer pages and mostly ignore your shorter news articles.    However, there is always a chance that those short news blurbs get marked as low quality by Google.  If that happens, it have a negative impact on your site as a whole.

To be safe you could prevent Googlebot from crawling all your short new blurbs by putting a rule like `Disallow: /news/` in your robots.txt file.  That would prevent all of the news stories in the `/news/` folder from getting crawled.  Google would be very unlikely to send significant traffic to any of them or view your site as low quality because of them.

If you really want them to get traffic initially when they are fresh, you could instead put a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag in the head of the page after a month.   That would prevent Google from seeing a large number of them on your site while still allowing the fresh ones to appear in Google News.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your post shows that you want to create content for search engines. However, this contradicts to the **[basic principles of the Google Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769)**:

> *Make pages primarily for users, not for search engines.*

If you create 20,000 web pages with whining and boredom then it is unlikely to have a high search rank and lead high organic traffic to your website. But one web page with unique and interesting content can be in the top search.

Summary: **focus your attention on quality but not on quantity**.

Comment: You would be silly to create internet content and not try to make it appealing to search engines.  Nothing in the question indicates to me that they are trying to create content primarily for search engines.  It sounds like they are excited and knowledgeable about a topic and they want to make sure that search engines will recommend it when appropriate.  That is so I want for my own website too.   This answer doesn't even attempt to address the content length question they have.   Please don't be so condescending and rude when answering.